# Positioning a label in the correct place dependent on whether it is an error or a success

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-validate

Sorry if this is too simple a question, but it is one that I have been trying to solve for a while.

I am trying to use Jquery Validate on a simple form, and I basically have everything working as it should, however I would like to place the message label generated by the validation in different places pending on whether it is an error or a success.
Currently, I can either get both of them before or after the field. I would like any errors to populate before the field, and successes to populate after the field.

Currently when it is a success the class `valid` is added to the label.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whyEnBe/9yLbmqzv/1/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="new_user">
   <input class="row" id="name" name="user_name" placeholder="Name" required="required" type="text">
</form>
```

This is my most recent attempt:

JS:

```
$("#new_user").validate({
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("valid").text(" ✓ ")
    },
    errorClass: "invalid",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (error.hasClass("valid") == "valid" ) {
            alert("valid");
            error.insertAfter(element);
        } else {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Please do not edit the OP to render parts of the answers meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error.hasClass("valid") == "valid"` makes no sense.  `.hasClass()` returns a boolean so you would not need to compare that to `"valid"`.  `if (error.hasClass("valid"))` would be enough.

Regardless, the root problem here is two-fold:

1. the `errorPlacement` function fires *before* the `class` is applied to the elements.
2. the `errorPlacement` function fires one time and does not continue to fire whenever something changes.  It's sole purpose is to place the error message element within the layout.  Once that's done, the plugin merely toggles it.  Therefore, you cannot use `errorPlacement` to dynamically change the placement of the label depending on a class.

---

However, since [the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) fire whenever the field toggles between invalid/valid, you can use these two options to place the checkmark instead of `success` and the default error message container.

1. Put an empty `<span></span>` container after each input element.

   ```
   <input type="text" name="foo"><span class="checkmark"></span>
   ```
2. Use `$(element).next('span').text(" ✓ ")` and `$(element).next('span').empty()` to add/remove the checkmark...

The rest of the code within these two functions is the default and must be left in place if you want to maintain the default functionality.

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === 'radio') {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    };
    $(element).next('span.checkmark').empty(); // remove the checkmark
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === 'radio') {
        this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    };
    $(element).next('span.checkmark').text(" ✓ "); // add a checkmark
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/o53ao9z6/**

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, what would you recommend I do?

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch. Especially for explaining everything!